# References to the panels missing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I click the OK button of the win or lose panel on the GameScene it takes me back to the MenuScene and shows the title screen instead of the level select screen.
The references to the paneles are missing before changing scene, how can I keep them through them?

StartManager

```
public GameObject startPanel, levelPanel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPanel.SetActive(true);
        levelPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        startPanel.SetActive(false);
        levelPanel.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void Home()
    {
        startPanel.SetActive(true);
        levelPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
```

I expected the levelPanel to be active

Comment: On scene change, all objects are destroyed. Except those `DontDestroyOnLoad` was called upon. That's how you should keep them. However, the question is quite unclear for me.

Comment: Yeah, i was using DontDestroyOnLoad, but the references to both panels was missing anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public GameObject startPanel, levelPanel;
public static bool OpenLevelPanel;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // Check OpenLevelPanel Bool Setting That;
    startPanel.SetActive(!OpenLevelPanel);
    levelPanel.SetActive(OpenLevelPanel);
}

public void PlayGame()
{
    startPanel.SetActive(false);
    levelPanel.SetActive(true);
}

public void Home()
{
    startPanel.SetActive(true);
    levelPanel.SetActive(false);
}
```

On Button Ok Click

```
StartManager.OpenLevelPanel = true;
//Switch Scene...
```